# Can we install a FAB(Fuse Application Bundle) on the WSO2 application server

Tags: wso2, fuseesb, jbossfuse, wso2-as

As the title says, I would like to know if I can deploy fab bundles on the WSO2 application server. One way I guess this is possible is to install the fab-bundle feature and then deploy the fab jar but would like a confirmation of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. FAB requires Karaf/Fuse as the OSGi application server.

Notice that FAB is deprecated and to be removed in the next Fuse 6.2 release.